# Can I sell my own CMS based on another CMS (e.g. WordPress) and encrypt the source code?

Tags: gpl, derivative-works, commercial, source-code

Can I recode WordPress or another CMS and then sell it as my own?

Can I encrypt the source code?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by recode? And what would be the license you intend to use?

Comment: CMS = Content Management System?

Comment: Whether it's a CMS or not is completely irrelevant.  What license were you granted when you obtained your copy?  You did read that didn't you?  (I ask that as one of the few people I know who actually does. :-)

Comment: @philippe-ombredanne recode for specific purposes. I'm going to remove needless code, add my own and customize CMS for myself.

Comment: What would be the purpose of the encryption?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I recode wordpress or another CMS and then sell it as my own?  recode for specific purposes. I'm going to remove needless code, add my own and customize CMS for myself

As long as the license allows it yes. The [Wordpress license](https://wordpress.org/about/license/) is the GPL-2.0. The GPL allows modification, redistribution and commercialization all right.

But it also has some obligations that I need to follow if I make such modifications. At a high level I would need to do all of these leaving aside some details:

1. document the changes I made and keep all the original notices, license texts, etc and ensure that my customers know about these terms
2. keep the code, these changes and my additions under the GPL
3. make the modified source code available to my customers in a form that is the preferred form for modification under the GPL which would mean plain source code.

> Can I encrypt source code?

I surely can encrypt the source code of a modified GPL-licensed project! But I would still need to make this source code including my modifications available to my customers in a form that is the preferred form for further modification. Under and per the GPL, this would mean that I would have to also distribute the source code unencrypted making the encryption rather moot.

/HTH

Comment: Sending code encrypted might be a requirement in a scenario as imagined in https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.html.en#DevelopChangesUnderNDA - though "selling it as your own" won't describe this, of course.